# Приём методом любого объекта как Object

Tags: java, android

```
package objtransfering;

public class ObjTransfering {
    public static void printEvrth(Object... args) {
        for (Object it : args)
            System.out.println(it);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printEvrth(new Integer(1), new Double(5.00), new String("end."));
    }
}
```

Все классы наследуют класс `Object`. К примеру, обёртка `Integer` наследует класс `Number`, а он, в свою очередь, `Object`. Выходит, у класса `Integer` есть поля и методы, которых нет у класса `Object`.
Тогда почему принимая объекты типа `Object` метод `System.out.println()` различает в них `Integer`, `Double` и `String`? Разве у этих объектов не "отбросилась" та часть, которая отличает их от `Object`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В [исходном коде](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream) видно, что метод `println()` перегружен и принимает один из множества типов аргументов.

Во время исполнения JVM определяет какой именно тип объекта передаётся по ссылке типа `Object` и вызывает соответствующий метод. При этом ООП обёртки над примитивами типа `Integer` или `Double`, да и остальные типы, наследующие `Object` могут иметь переопределённый метод `toString()`, коий и будет выведен в консоль. Обычно этот метод выводит имя класса и `hashCode` объекта. В случае же приведённых вами классов там иной код. Например [`Integer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28%29) выводит только число.

При этом, конечно же, никакая информация не теряется о конкретном типе объекта присвоенного ссылке. Единственное ограничение - вы не сможете вызвать методы конкретного класса, пока вы его не скастуете к его настоящему типу.

Comment: Т.е. в его случае вызывается [эта перегрузка `println`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29), которая вызывает метод [`valueOf`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) класса `String`, который в свою очередь вызывает метод `toString` класса `Object`, далее посредством таблицы виртуальных функций _JVM_ вызывается переопределенный наследником (`Integer`, `Double` и `String`) метод `toString`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. На самом деле, только вы написали именно то, что я ожидал прочитать: что информация не теряется, но я не могу обращаться к методам/полям наследника. Также очень интересует дополнение товарища @StateltPrimitive , выходит, JVM всё-же вызывает свой метод `.toString()` для каждого класса. Это справедливо для всех классов или только для `Object`? Например, я создам свой класс, унаследую его в другом классе и дополню новыми методами. И после преобразования объекта второго класса в первый, можно будет обращаться(через ссылку на объект первого класса) к уникальным методам второго?

Comment: @heroys6 Если вы экземпляр второго класса (`Child`) передадите в метод, у которого типом параметра является первый класс (`Parent`), то сделав явное приведение типа пришедшего в метод экземпляра с типом `Parent` к типу `Child` (если динамический тип параметра и правда `Child`, то приведение типов пройдет успешно, иначе вылетит соответствующее исключение) вы сумеете обращаться непосредственно к методам наследника. А вообще, даже без приведения типов, вызывая методы родителя вызовутся методы наследника (если в нем переопределены таковые) за счет таблицы виртуальных функций.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive всё-таки, немного неясно. В моём случае, тип параметра `Parent` принимал разные `Child` аргументы. Как дальше JVM вызывала для бывшего `Integer`(принятого как `Object`) перегруженный `.toString()` именно `Integer` класса, а не `Double` или ещё какого-нибудь `Child` класса? Выходит, система заранее знает, что работает не с `Object`, где `.toString()` виртуальный

Comment: @heroys6 Все дело в [таблице виртуальных функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2) (ознакомьтесь с материалами о ней). Экземпляр класса в _Java_ содержит ссылку на таблицу виртуальных методов своего класса (а в _Java_ по умолчанию все методы виртуальные).Таблица методов класса после загрузки и динамического связывания класса в конечном счете содержит ссылки на методы данного класса.

Comment: Если метод определен в данном классе, то это будет ссылка на метод данного класса, если определен в наследнике, то ссылка на метод наследника, если в суперклассе, это будет ссылка на метод суперкласса.

Answer (score 3):

У класса `Object` есть метод `toString()` при использовании `System.out.println()` вызывается этот метод. В свою очередь `toString()` переопределен в классах `Integer`, `Double` и `String`, и у каждого из них своя реализация этого метода.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы загляните внутрь данных объектов, то обнаружите такой волшебный метод, как `toString`.

Этот метод служит для представления объекта в виде строки.

У каждого класса реализация метода своя. К примеру у `Integer` такой код:

```html
public static String toString(int i, int radix) {
        if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX)
            radix = 10;

        /* Use the faster version */
        if (radix == 10) {
            return toString(i);
        }

        char buf[] = new char[33];
        boolean negative = (i < 0);
        int charPos = 32;

        if (!negative) {
            i = -i;
        }

        while (i <= -radix) {
            buf[charPos--] = digits[-(i % radix)];
            i = i / radix;
        }
        buf[charPos] = digits[-i];

        if (negative) {
            buf[--charPos] = '-';
        }

        return new String(buf, charPos, (33 - charPos));
}
```

Как видим метод возвращает строку (грубо говоря) `return new String(buf, charPos, (33 - charPos));`

У других классов всё тоже самое. 
В любом классе можно тоже его реализовать.

Можно написать там все что угодно, хоть `return "hello, world";`

А этот самый `System.out.println` неявно вызывает этот самый метод `toString` у объекта

---

Добавлю пожалуй пример:

```html
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
  
  Test test = new Test();
  
  System.out.print(test);
 }
 
 
 public static class Test {
  
  public String toString() {
   return "Hello, world!";
  }
 }
}
```

https://ideone.com/jLvbDM

Comment: Я на 2 секунды опередил)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я просто чихал)))

Comment: Будьте здоровы)

Comment: Эх долго я писал((